# dataWithContentsOfURL iOS HTTPS self-signed certificate

Tags: ios, https, certificate

I'm trying to download a JSON object from a page hosted on a web server, using the method

`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://<url>"]]`

but it doesn't work. The same call with the same address with `http://` instead of `https://` works. The server has a self-signed certificate, and it's not trusted by iOS (by default).

What can I do to make it trustable by my app?

Comment: I would really like to know that too :) Have you found the answer?

Comment: No, no way to do that. I only encrypted the content of the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `+dataWithContentsOfURL:` for this. Use `NSURLConnection` directly, which gives you delegate methods to properly control authentication.